# "How to Prevent multiple events C#?"

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I have textbox control with auto postback = "true" in update panel and there is save button with access key of "Alt + s" when i change something into textbox and without losing focus if user has pressed "Alt + s" than need to call first text change event of textbox and then should fire save click event once as there is some calculation on text change event.In this situation first it fires text change event than it call save click event and than it calls again text change event.

Is there any good approach to resolve issue either client side or server side or from sql side?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Val" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"                                
 OnTextChanged="Txt_Val_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Btn_Save"  runat="server" OnClick="Btn_Save_Click" 
Text="Save" AccessKey="S" ValidationGroup="S"/>

</ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

   protected void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Save data into database
   }

  protected void Txt_Val_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       // Some calculation
  }
```

Comment: How about instead of keeping your operations bound to `events` create separate methods for both `text_changed` and `Save_click` which you can call from the events as well as from outside(*for you the **ALT+S** case.*).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :
Here the Microsoft provide the Control.Update Method documentation here `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update?view=netframework-4.8`. its last update value store in Database.

Solution 2 :
please check your event its some another event call then sometimes this issue is given.

Solution 3 :
you Set focus after a update a value in the page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

second time set focus and after update is a 3rd solution for this issue.

I hope the above three solutions is helpful.

Comment: I can't use solution 3 : as there are multiple text boxes with auto post back = true and in this scenario user has not leave textbox just he change value in textbox and press "Alt + s"

Solution 1 : this is web page so i cant use Control.update
this issue arise as u mentioned in solution 2 but its issue not solution

Comment: yes I understand but But you save a value in the database and in a save time focus hide on textbox so, I suggest next time you update value then textbox focus.

Answer (score 0):

> when i change something into textbox and without losing focus if user has pressed "Alt + s" than need to call first text change event of textbox and then should fire save click event once as there is some calculation on text change event

quoted statement can also be handled like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Val" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"                                
 OnTextChanged="Txt_Val_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Btn_Save"  runat="server" OnClick="Btn_Save_Click" 
Text="Save" AccessKey="S" ValidationGroup="S" OnClientClick="return verifyFirst();" />

</ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
function verifyFirst(){
   return verifyChangedText($('[id$=Txt_Val]'));
}

function verifyChangedText(elem){
    //verify your stuff on client level.
    //if you need to do the server side stuff, hit WebMethod using ajax
    //finally according to the result
    if(everythingIsOk){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}  
</script>
```

`onClientClick` executes first on client side, if everything is satisfactory the return bool value if true it executes the server side event call `OnClick="Btn_Save_Click"` and if its false then it doesn't execute the server side event call.

**UPDATED**

> I have multiple textboxes with text change event on page or in grid for each text box control it will be difficult to handle

as per your comment quoted above, you can handle multiple TextBox verification 
but it can only be handled in following manner:

if a user presses enter without focusing out then we don't know on which TextBox user made changes to so we will have to check all the TextBoxes present in the form and fire each TextBox's onkeypress event.

for e.g:

```js
i = 0;
function verifyMe(event,args){
    debugger;
    $(args).text(i += 1);
  };
  
function verifyThisStuff(){
 var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
   $('.forVerification').each(function(){
  $(this).trigger(e); 
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="forVerification" onkeypress="return verifyMe(event,'#span1');">
<input type="text" class="forVerification" onkeypress="return verifyMe(event,'#span2');">
<button type="button" onclick="return verifyThisStuff();">click Me</button>

<p>textbox 1 Keypresses: <span id="span1">0</span></p>

<p>textbox 2 Keypresses: <span id="span2">0</span></p>
```

Comment: I have multiple textboxes with text change event on page or in grid for each text box control it will be difficult to handle

Comment: I have tried as per above code but still it is not working